# Как сделать gnome panel прозрачной в окружении unity 2d?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, ubuntu-unity

Перешарил множество папок, и конфиги пытался править, и заменять графические элементы, но ничего не получеться. Буду очень признателен за ваши советы и ответы, заранее огромное спасибо!  Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

Если не изменяет память,в меню со всеми настройками есть вход через апплет выключения и перезагрузки системы,там либо настройки либо конфигурация-должна быть вкладка из нее все и должно настраиваться!Я как то искал расскладку клавиатуры,а она там оказалось)))Впринцепи по клику ПКМ в свойствах должны быть настройки(default)